# Undefined reference to boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction

I try to compile small .cpp file with boost library on remote server on Debian using g++ 4.4. I use Netbeans for this purpose. My home machine is on windows 7. After resolving some issues with linking next code

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer ac; //line 5
    return 0; //line 6
}
```

Produces 2 errors:
line 5: `undefined reference to boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::auto_cpu_timer(short)'` 
line 6: `undefined reference to boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::~auto_cpu_timer()'`

Same result if i use header `boost/thread.hpp` but for thread constructor/destructor. 
But for example `boost/shared_ptr` compiles without any problem. 
Result compile command in neatbeans is

```
g++ -m64 -I/usr/include/boost/boost_1_49_0    -lboost_system -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/test build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o
-L/usr/include/boost/boost_1_49_0/stage/lib -Wl,-rpath /usr/include/boost/boost_1_49_0/stage/lib  build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o
```

What i missed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to link against boost_timer. Add `-lboost_timer` to the gcc command line. Consult the Netbeans documentation on how to add libraries to a project.