# Boost timer undefined reference error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

I have been trying to run a simple example program from [boost 1.48 docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html):

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
  boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;

  for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    std::sqrt(123.456L); // burn some time

  return 0;
}
```

I'm on a Ubuntu 12.04 system and I installed the libboost-all-dev package using apt-get. The program doesn't compile. There are several undefined reference errors:

```
/tmp/ccSLnBrE.o: In function `main':
cpp-timer.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::auto_cpu_timer(short)'
cpp-timer.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::~auto_cpu_timer()'
/tmp/ccSLnBrE.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
cpp-timer.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
cpp-timer.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
cpp-timer.cpp:(.text+0xc7): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is not a generic question about undefined reference errors. It is more specific to the Boost Library. Therefore it isn't answered by this question: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

In other answers regarding more [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565117/undefined-reference-to-boosttimerauto-cpu-timer) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467072/c-boost-undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category) the solution was to link the libraries using a -lboost_timer flag. However on doing the same I get this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_timer
```

Comment: Do yo have `libboost_system.a` and `libboost_timer.a` files on the linker path?

Comment: I solved my problem by downloading and building from the source.

However I still don't have these files in my filesystem.